# Code Academy: Unit 5 (Blocks & Sorting): Methodical Sorting

Tags: ruby

This works if I use alphabetize(a, true) or alphabetize(a):

```
def alphabetize(arr, rev=false)
    if rev == true
        arr.sort.reverse!
    else
        arr.sort!
    end    
end
```

But this won't work for the default case when I enter arr as my only parameter, alphabetize(a) or alphabetize(a, true) but only works for alphabetize(a, true):

```
def alphabetize(arr, rev=false)
    arr.sort!
    if rev == true
        arr.sort.reverse!
    end    
end
```

Could anyone explain why?

Comment: Are you sure that second example works for alphabetize(a, false), it should only for alphabetize(a, true)?

Comment: Sorry, you are correct.  It only works for alphabetize(a, true).  thank you for catching that.

Answer (score 2):

The method `Array#sort!` (notice the bang) performs a **in-place** sort, which means the original array gets sorted.

```
array = [1, 3, 4, 5, 2]
array.sort!  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The method `Array#sort` (no bang) does not change the original array, instead it returns a new array which is sorted.

```
array = [1, 3, 4, 5, 2]
array.sort  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array  #=> [1, 3, 4, 5, 2]
```

So your problem is at line 4 which always reverses a new array other than your original one.

P.S. before you write down your code, think carefully what you expect your code to do. Should your code modify the original array?

If your answer is yes, then your code should be

```
# By convention, in-place modification method names end with a !
def alphabetize!(arr, rev=false)
  arr.sort!

  # Don't use rev == true. It's redundant.
  arr.reverse! if rev

  arr
end
```

If your answer is no, then

```
def alphabetize(arr, rev=false)
  new_array = arr.sort

  # Think why I'm using in-place reverse here.
  new_array.reverse! if rev

  new_array
end
```

Comment: Aetherus,Thank you very much for your response.  I understand your point about the modifying the array and I appreciate you pointing that out to me.  I tried the modification you suggested, both reversing the new array and rearranging the original one.  The problem is I still get the same error that is does not do the default case when a second parameter is not included.    Any possible input?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Aetherus answer is great but I think that doesn't cover your case completely, the reason why your second example is not working is related to Ruby way of handling return statements. If return statement is not explicitly defined method will return the last statement and in your second example your last statement

```
    if rev == true
      arr.sort.reverse!
    end
```

returns nil when rev is false so your method is not returning the value you're expecting.

UPDATE

If you want your second example to work, you should do this:

```
def alphabetize(arr, rev=false)
  return arr.sort! if !rev
  if rev == true
    arr.sort.reverse!
  end    
end
```

But you really shouldn't be doing this...

Comment: Jovica, Thank you for your comment as well as pointing out my mistake in the question.  I have fixed that.  I think I understand your comment.  Please forgive this question, but I am new to coding.  Does the if statement work such that if it is true then it will carry out that loop and exit if it isn't?  If so, shouldn't it just ignore the if statement if I leave out the second argument because then it should default to the false case and sort without reversing the arry?     Thanks again and I look forward to your response!

Comment: You corrected just the part of your question, now you're saying that alphabetize(a, true) don't word and alphabetize(a, true) works. Regarding your question, your problem is about returning stuff from method. In almost all programming languages function(or method in Ruby) must have return keyword. This keyword defines what will be returned from method. Ruby allow you to omit return keyword if you want your last statement from method to be returned. In your second example your last statement is if ... end block and since it doesn't return anything Ruby this method will return no value.

Comment: If this is not clear to you read here more about methods and the way that Ruby handles return. https://launchschool.com/books/ruby/read/methods

Comment: There's a few typos in my comment, it should be work instead of word in first sentence and in the last - "since it doesn't return anything (Ruby) this method will return no value" Ruby should be removed.

Comment: Hi Jovica,  Thank you for your responses.  I am sorry but I think I was not very clear in my original posting.  I checked my methods with another line calling the method as such:  alphabetize(array)-worked-1st method.

Comment: No problem, but you asked why your second example is not working, we already know that 1st method is working.

Comment: Hi Jovica,  Thank you for your responses.  I am sorry I did not mention that I used puts to call the methods.  Result: 2nd method:  alphabetize(array, true): worked.  2nd method: alphabetize(array, false): did not work.  2nd method alphabetize(array):  did not work.  I also implemented the code lines you suggested and could not get it to work either except with the true case.  Any feedback would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You were right about my redundancy!  :)  I'll be more careful.

Comment: Ok, seems from your comments that you didn't understand me good, code that I placed in my answer is not solution to your problem, you should read my comments more carefully. I'll update my answer to make your second example to work, but you asked why it's not working not how to make it work.